# Register New user using Social Login in Broadleaf Ecommerce

Tags: facebook-login, google-signin, broadleaf-commerce

I have followed the spring social integration tutorial and I am now able to allows users to social-sigin on my website using Google, Facebook and Linkedin.

Now, when the user successfully authenticates from the social site and comes back to my application, he is being presented with a registration page with email, first name, last name fields pre-filled. He needs to insert the password. I am extending "BroadleafSocialRegisterController" in my "RegisterController".

Now, what I actually want to do is this :-

- Once a user successfully authenticates and comes back to my site, I want to Login them as a new user and directly "Log them in" , instead of again presenting them with register page. Its NO point in asking for registration even when user wants to use his social-site credentials.
- When user authenticates from social site, I need to create a new user in my DB with his email-id and name ( Which I am already getting ), with some default password, so that when next times he uses his social login, I should login him, instead of taking him to register page.

How can I achieve this. I am very close , just need that last thread. I am already having the social login working and after social-site authentication, user is login on register page with all details (except password) prefilled.

I have followed the blog given on Broadleaf website and that made me work with setting up login through facebook, google and linkedin.

But, In my current flow after successful validation from social site
at the end - user is Redirect to REGISTER PAGE with Email, First  & last name pre-filled.

But,  want the user to be logged in, in the last step instead of going to register.

For example, if you go to Stackoverflow and login using google, you are just logged into the site and not sent to register page with prefilled values. So, this is exactly what I want.

Let me know where I need to change and what ?

- Sumit Rathore

Answer (score 0):

I had similar kind of situation and I followed this link http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/blog/why-your-ecommerce-site-should-integrate-with-spring-social

Comment: Hi Prabhat, 

Thanks for responding. I have acutally followed the same tutorial and got everything working in my application.
In my current flow after successful validation from social site
at the end - user is Redirect to REGISTER PAGE with Email, First  & last name pre-filled.

But,  want the user to be logged in, in the last step instead of going to register.

For example, if you go to Stackoverflow and login using google, you are just logged into the site and not sent to register page with prefilled values. So, this is exactly what I want. 

Let me know where I need to change and what ?

Comment: @SumitRathore if you have followed the url then after successful social login you would get redirected to "signUpUrl" which in this case is "/register". Now the approach I have taken is to have a different request mapping to capture successful social login and set random password for the user. Once this is done I used existing BLC logic to register the customer and redirect them to home page. 

So in short you can say that I bypassed registration page and handled everything on code level.

Comment: That is what I want. Actually whats happening is the "SignUpUrl" is actually passed in "applicationContext-Servlet.xml" in "ProviderSignInController.java" 
   <!-- <property name="applicationUrl" value="${application.url}" />  -->

But, as discussion forum in Spring website, there is a problem with this controller and it doesn't not have setter for applicationUrl, which throws a deployment exception if passed. So, I commented it and this seems to be the problem. 

Can you tell me your approach and the files which you have changed. so that I can have the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well I do not see any problem with ProviderSignInController. Spring docs says setApplicationUrl method is present in this class. Probably there must be some other problem that you are facing. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ProviderSignInController.html